# There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified

Tags: sql

I have written this query.

```
String insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO PurchasesDetails (PurchasesID, SupplierID,
    Date,BatchNo, Quantity, TotalAmount)
    VALUES
    ('" + txtPurchasesID.Text.Trim() + "','" + null + "','" +
    comboBatchNo.SelectedValue + "','" + comboProductType.SelectedValue +
    "','" + datePurchases.Value.ToString() + "','" +txtUnitPrice.Text.Trim() +
    "','" + txtQuantity.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtTotalAmount.Text.Trim()+ "')";
```

But I am getting this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: There are fewer columns in the INSERT
>   statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of
>   values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified
>   in the INSERT statement.

Comment: How does the insertQuery string look with values added?

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question, and also tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: You're specifying 8 values, with only 6 columns mentioned.  In addition, if you want to insert a literal SQL `NULL`, then you should use the text `null`, not the `null` from your app language.

Comment: To extend @TimBiegeleisen's comment; change `"','" + null + "','"` to `"',null,'"`

Comment: @Flater No...the OP should be using a prepared statement almost certainly.  But yes, your suggestion would partially fix this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: A minimalchange often makes the core of the issue clearer. A larger rework generally muddies the water as to what the specific problem was. Many other improvements can be suggested (avoiding SQL injection, for one), but they distract from the actual question.

Comment: @Flater No, I disagree.  Statements _are_ the best answer to all these problems.  They alleviate the need to worry about string and other formatting, besides the injection component.  Injection isn't the only reason to use statements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your last comment argues against points I never made.

Comment: Thanks Sir! But the problem is solved.

Comment: I was considering adding a little blurb about prepared statements to my answer (I didn't see the comments until after I clicked "Add answer", sorry for stealing your collective thunder!), but intially decided against it because it seemed off-topic for this particular question, though it's something that OP definitely should consider (and would mean that you won't need to define `"NULL"` in a string at all!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a literal `null` string in your code, this should instead be a string that says `"NULL"`.